# How to delete data from TP log file?

Tags: kdb

One of my rtdbs went down due to really large TP log file and host not having enough memory to bring the process back up. The culprit is one of the tables in which bogus data was sent. Is there a way to delete this particular table’s data from TP log file so that eod roll is not affected? 
I don’t have a wdb running in there and would like to retain data for other tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you manually overwrite you upd function you can through away the problem table
See example below

```
q)//create a sample tplog 
q)`:tplog set ()
`:tplog
q)hopen `:tplog
3i
q)3 enlist (`upd;`t;([]1 2 3;10 20 30;`a`b`c))
3
q)3 enlist (`upd;`t;([]1 2 3;10 20 30;`a`b`c))
3
q)3 enlist (`upd;`badTable;([]1 2 3;10 20 30;`a`b`c))
3
q)3 enlist (`upd;`t;([]1 2 3;10 20 30;`a`b`c))
3
```

normal replay

```
q)upd:upsert
q)-11!`:tplog
4
q)t
x x1 x2
-------
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 c
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 c
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 c
q)badTable
x x1 x2
-------
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 c
q)delete from `. //clear everything
`.
```

throw away badTable

```
q)upd:{$[x=`badTable;(::);x upsert y]}
q)-11!`:tplog
4
q)t
x x1 x2
-------
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 c
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 c
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 c
q)badTable //badTable no longer exists 
'badTable
  [0]  badTable
       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

As emc211 mentioned (though didn't quite show in the example) the approach in the RDB would be to have a custom upd function that filters out the bad data.

If the bad data is isolated to a particular table:

```
upd:{if[x<>`badTableName;x insert y]};
```

If the bad data is contained in a "good" table:

```
upd:{$[x=`goodTable;x insert select from ($[1<count first y;flip;enlist][cols[x]!y]) where notBadData;x insert y]};
```

Then replay using `-11!` and savedown.

Ultimately you will probably also want to save a cleansed log file in case you ever need to replay it again in the future. To do that you could use a similar upd function to above except instead of inserting the data in memory you would write the good records back to a new log file along the lines of

```
q)L:`:/path/to/cleansedLogFile;
q).[L;();:;()];
q)lh:hopen L;

upd:{if[x<>`badTableName;lh enlist (`upd;x;y)]};
upd:{$[x=`goodTable;lh enlist (`upd;x;value flip select from ($[1<count first y;flip;enlist][cols[x]!y]) where notBadData);lh enlist (`upd;x;y)]};
```

Then again replay using `-11!` and when complete `hclose lh`.

Comment: thanks terry, think you could just see the example at the bottom as had to scroll through the code block, split it up so easier to read

Comment: @emc211 Got it, I see it now